# How to give the path to run a jar file from a servlet?

Tags: servlets

I am facing a problem in running a jar file from my servlet.
I have to run a jar file of another java application with arguments in a separate sevlet in web project in Eclipse.

I use the code as

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar myproject.jar param1 param2 abc.xml");
```

In above code, on running the above jar file with parameters param1 and param2 , it will store output in abc.xml.
But the problem is that i dont know how to give the path of myproject.jar in code.

I copied myproject.jar to the project directory and it does not give any output.
I have tried to use
I dont know how to give path of jar file and where to put the jar file and where the out put file will come .

This code works fine with simple core java application where i put my myproject.jar file in the core java project directory and the output file abc.xml is created in the core java project directory.

Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: out of curiosity, why not create the classes and call the methods in the jar rather than trying to call its main method? Or have you coded everything in the main method of your jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right way of invoking Java code contained in some JAR in the classpath (I assume that you have placed it in `/WEB-INF/lib`). Just import and invoke the code contained in that JAR file directly.

```
import com.packagefromjar.SomeMainClassInJar;

// ...

SomeMainClassInJar.main(new String[] { "param1", "param2", "/path/to/abc.xml" });
```

Or if that API is well designed, then just use its entry classes directly instead of calling a `main()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine but this jar gives the one output in file and one out put in console s my main need is to save the output of console in a stream.In your solution my question is that how can i save the output of the console in a stream?